# What would be the type of the object returned by the DynamoDB when an object with subset of the attributes accesses an item?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am very new to DynamoDB. I have this doubt:

Let's consider a DDB table having the items with following attributes: **<attr1, attr2, attr3>**

Now I have the following 2 Java classes:

class1:

```
package packageName;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.*;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = class1.TABLE_NAME)
public class class1 {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tableName";
    public static final String ATTR1 = "Attr1";
    public static final String ATTR2 = "Attr2";
    public static final String ATTR3 = "Attr3";

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = ATTR1)
    private String attr1;

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = ATTR2)
    private String attr2;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = ATTR3)
    private String attr3;
}
```

class2:

```
package packageName;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.*;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = class2.TABLE_NAME)
public class class1 {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tableName";
    public static final String ATTR1 = "Attr1";
    public static final String ATTR2 = "Attr2";

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = ATTR1)
    private String attr1;

    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = ATTR2)
    private String attr2;
}
```

When I use this lines of code:

```
class2 class2Obj = mapper.load(class2Obj.class,attr1Val,attr2Val); // mapper is the DynamoDBMapper object.
```

Will the mapper return an object of class2?

If not, is there any other way using the mapper to get an item from the table as a class2 object?

P.S. I don't have DDB available to check this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can load a subset of an item's attributes.

There are some limitations, though: to load an item you need to use the partition key attribute and the sort key attribute (if the table has both partition and sort key). Same if you use an index.

Second, while you can load an item with a subset of the attributes, be careful with updates. Trying to save an item loaded that way may clobber the attributes not loaded (depending on how you save)

Lastly, you may create a Local Secondary Index ([LSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html)) or a Global Secondary Index ([GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html)) and take advantage of attribute projections to optimize your queries.